# Change default socket buffer size under Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, registry

An application I cannot change is dropping some incoming UDP packets.  I suspect that the receive buffer is overflowing.  Is there a registry setting to make the default buffer larger than 8KB?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098897/what-is-the-largest-safe-udp-packet-size-on-the-internet) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900697/how-to-find-the-largest-udp-packet-i-can-send-without-fragmenting)

Comment: @ja_mesa My udp packets are TS over IP and always 7*188 = 1316 bytes.  I'm not concerned about fragmentation.

Comment: Making the receive buffer larger only moves the problem a bit. Either slow down the sender or speed up the receiver. And you can't eliminate packet loss in UDP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-winsock-buffer.html) 
To set the default size of the Windows use the following `DWORD` registry keys :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet\Services\Afd\Parameters]

DefaultReceiveWindow = 10240
DefaultSendWindow = 10240
```

Comment: Do I need to create DefaultReceiveWindow & DefaultSendWindow under  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet\Services\Afd\Parameters]? As these are not available in my registry.

Comment: You can try it, system reboot is required after changed.

Comment: Thanks. I added the values and rebooted my system. Set both values to 16384. I reached to this thread while looking for a solution to missing RTP packets during decoding RTSP stream using FFMPEG. I still see RTP packet drop from RTSP stream in the decoding process.

Comment: There is one API in socket can get the buffer size, Sorry I cannot recall it clearly, And I am using phone now. I will give you this API once I got it

Comment: @Tariq Please try `getsockopt` with parameter `SO_SNDBUF`, you can get the socket buffer size. BTW, you can set the size of socket buffer through `setsockopt` with parameter `SO_SNDBUF`.

Comment: Bad answer. Question is about UDP. Answer is about TCP.