# How to set maxumim UDP buffer size in windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, buffer, iperf

Running iperf tool client/server between windows7 and linux.
In Linux UDP buffer size set to maximum using cmd "sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608"(rmem/wmem) and trying to push 1Gb of data successfully.
How to increase or set to **max UDP buffer size** in windows machine?
What are the registry keys/values need to add?

Answer (score -1):

From here: [Change default socket buffer size under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985816/change-default-socket-buffer-size-under-windows)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet\Services\Afd\Parameters]

DefaultReceiveWindow = 10240
DefaultSendWindow = 10240
```

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: There is no improvement with given values.

Comment: Hi Balu, were they the values you were looking for? Or are you looking for different values?

Comment: That answer deals with TCP, not UDP.