# WSAGetLastError() never return WSAEWOULDBLOCK when nonblock send return -1，why?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, tcp, nonblocking

In Windows, when nonblock send return -1, WSAGetLastError() returns WSAENOBUFS, not WSAEWOULDBLOCK, which is different from linux.

How can I have WSAGetLastError() return WSAEWOULDBLOCK?

Answer (score 2):

Those are two completely different error conditions.

`WSAEWOULDBLOCK` means the socket send buffer is full and cannot accept more data without blocking the calling thread.

`WSAENOBUFS` means the underlying kernel buffer itself is full and cannot accept more data at all.  This is an good indication that you are sending way too much data to the socket at one time.  Under normal conditions, you should not be getting this error.

Here is an interesting tidbit from Microsoft's KB:

[Design issues - Sending small data segments over TCP with Winsock](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214397)

> To optimize performance at the application layer, **Winsock copies data buffers from application send calls to a Winsock kernel buffer**. Then, the stack uses its own heuristics (such as Nagle algorithm) to determine when to actually put the packet on the wire. You can change the amount of Winsock kernel buffer allocated to the socket using the SO_SNDBUF option (it is 8K by default). **If necessary, Winsock can buffer significantly more than the SO_SNDBUF buffer size**. In most cases, the send completion in the application only indicates the data buffer in an application send call is copied to the Winsock kernel buffer and does not indicate that the data has hit the network medium. The only exception is when you disable the Winsock buffering by setting SO_SNDBUF to 0.
>
> Winsock uses the following rules to indicate a send completion to the application (depending on how the send is invoked, the completion notification could be the function returning from a blocking call, signaling an event or calling a notification function, and so forth):
>
> •If the socket is still within SO_SNDBUF quota, Winsock copies the data from the application send and indicates the send completion to the application.
>
> •If the socket is beyond SO_SNDBUF quota and there is only one previously buffered send still in the stack kernel buffer, Winsock copies the data from the application send and indicates the send completion to the application.
>
> •**If the socket is beyond SO_SNDBUF quota and there is more than one previously buffered send in the stack kernel buffer, Winsock copies the data from the application send. Winsock does not indicate the send completion to the application until the stack completes enough sends to put the socket back within SO_SNDBUF quota or only one outstanding send condition.**

`WSAENOBUFS` is reported when you are trying to send more data than the kernel can physically handle.

> WSAENOBUFS
>   10055
>  
>   No buffer space available.
>   An operation on a socket could not be performed because **the system lacked sufficient buffer space** or because a queue was full.

You need to break up your data into smaller chunks so that you do not overwhelm the kernel. Ideally, for best performance, you should not exceed the buffer size reported by `getsockopt(SO_SNDBUF)-1`.  But either way, when you do encounter `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` (which you should encounter before `WSAENOBUFS`), *STOP SENDING DATA* until the socket is ready to receive more data.  Depending on your code, that could be indicated by `select()` reporting the socket is writable, or by you receiving an `FD_WRITE` notification from `WSAAsyncSelect()`/`WSAEventSelect()`.

Comment: VG. I've never been able to make head or tail of this documentation, or indeed of why they didn't just raise their absurdly low buffer sizes instead of introducing all this complication.

Comment: You can use `setsockopt(SO_SNDBUF)` to raise the size of the socket send buffer, but you have no control over the buffer sizes of the underlying kernel.

Comment: @EJP: the kernel will happily buffer gigabytes of data under [at least some circumstances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28785626/886887).  I'm not sure buffer sizes are the issue here.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Why? All you need is a socket send buffer of an appropriate size. Nobody asked the kernel to buffer more than that. But the default size is was 8192, which was already far too small in the 1980s, and these other strange heuristics crept in, instead of fixing the buffer size.